# POST data using AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, python, django, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to post image file using the jQuery's ajax post method. Would it work if I just put the file data in the POST request's 'data' parameter?

I am using django framework. This is my first attempt:

```
$('#edit_user_image').change(function(){
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = document.getElementById("edit_user_image");
    var csrftoken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
    /* Create a FormData instance */

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);


    client.open("post", "/upload-image/", true);
    client.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=frontier");
    client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */ 
  });
```

The problem with this is that I don't get the'request.FILES' object on the serer side in my 'views.py'.

I also tried doing it with ajax post but it doesn't work either.

```
$('#edit_user_image').change(function(){
    var data = {csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
                content:document.getElementById("edit_user_image").files[0],}
    $.post("/upload-image/", data, function(){
    });
  });
```

Edit from one of the answers:

```
$('#edit_user_image').change(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($("#edit_user_image")[0]);

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST", 
      url: "/upload-image/",  
      xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
        // If you want to handling upload progress, modify below codes.
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
          myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', yourProgressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
        }
        return myXhr;
      },
      data: formData,  
      // Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // If you want to make it possible cancel upload, register cancel button handler.
        $("#yourCancelButton").click(xhr.abort);
      },
      success: function( data ) {  
        // Something to do after upload success.
        alert('File has been successfully uploaded.'); 
        location.reload();
      },
      error : function(xhr, textStatus) {
        // Something to do after upload failed.
        alert('Failed to upload files. Please contact your system administrator. - ' + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });  
  });
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: The 'post' request never happens.

Comment: You really need to provide some more information. What are you trying to accomplish? Posting an image file is possible if you have it base64 encoded but you'll need to server to be expecting base64. Just fill in some blanks and we'll help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my final working solution:

```
$('#edit_user_image').change(function(){
    var csrftoken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
    var formData = new FormData($("#edit_user_image")[0]);
    var formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append("file", $('#edit_user_image')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrftoken);

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST", 
      url: "/upload-image/",  
      data: formData, 
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false, 

    });  
  });
```

Comment: It works! I spent almost 2 days for googling and experiments! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), otherwise you have to use Flash or iframes or Plugins (these ones use flash or iframes), FormData comes with HTML5 so it won't work in IE <= 9, a great guy created a [replica](https://github.com/francois2metz/html5-formdata) of FormData for old browsers, to use it you only have to put **formdata.js** in the head tag. So in my opinion you have to use FormData.

We say you have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" name="form" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="img"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

you have to get the img chosen by the user so your javascript have to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url: :"/URL",
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data){},
            error: function(data){},
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        });
    });
});
```

and now you are going to be able to retrieve the img chosen by the user in django with:

```
request.FILES
```

Comment: This seems similar to the other answer. I have tried its code but i get 'Failed to upload files. Please contact your system administrator'

Comment: This is the only way, where do you get that error? in django?

Comment: No, did u read the snippet from the other answer. This error is caused if the ajax fails.

Comment: Yeah, but that's because something is broken in django etc., you can inspect the response with the google chrome's dev tools or firebug in Firefox.

Comment: If thats the case, I wonder what could be possibly wrong with this simple 'view':                                                     def upload_image(request):
  if request.method=="POST":
    if request.FILES:
      return HttpResponse( "AJAX" )
    else:
      return HttpResponse("bad")

Comment: Also, i saw it in the chrome dev tools, the POST is not made.

Comment: did you add, contentType:false and processData:false?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43647/discussion-between-monique-and-victor-castillo-torres)

Comment: Sure, I'm in the chat

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can post your image file using jQuery's ajax.

Try below code snippet.

```
// Your image file input should be in "yourFormID" form.
var formData = new FormData($("#yourFormID")[0]);

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", 
    url: "your_form_request_url",  
    xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
        // If you want to handling upload progress, modify below codes.
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', yourProgressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    data: formData,  
    // Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // If you want to make it possible cancel upload, register cancel button handler.
        $("#yourCancelButton").click(xhr.abort);
    },
    success: function( data ) {  
        // Something to do after upload success.
        alert('File has been successfully uploaded.'); 
        location.reload();
    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus) {
        // Something to do after upload failed.
        alert('Failed to upload files. Please contact your system administrator. - ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I got this using above code: 'Failed to upload files. Please contact your system administrato'

Comment: What is the xhr.responseText?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is add "return false after the ajax block.