# pass file path to django view using ajax post method

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am using ajax to post data
In form one file input is there
I want to get the path of that file field and send it django view through ajax

I am trying to do this but i am getting fakepath

```
var path = $('input[type=file][name=fileone]').val();
alert(path);


path i am getting is C:\fakepath\django_files.ods
```

How can i get the actual path so i can send that to backend.

Help me for this
i am ajax post methos

Comment: What would be the point of sending the actual path on the client? The server can't use that in any way.

Comment: then how can i send the file to the view?

Comment: You may try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822823/django-jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: I've used http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ in the past and it works really well. ```form.ajaxSubmit()``` is what you'll use.

Comment: How can i use jquery/ajax i tried but its not worked.