# Django/Python: Not being able to send file to the view

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have this form:

```
<form  id="formi"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
   <div>
      <input id="some_file_input" type="file"  name="some_file"">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="upload-file-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my view, it receives a file from that form:

```
def d_s_w(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":

        if len(request.FILES) != 0:

            data = request.FILES['some_file']

            ...

            context = {'dates': dates, 'users': users}

            data = json.dumps(context)

            return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
        else:
            raise Http404("No File uploaded")
    else:
        raise Http404("No POST data was given.")
```

I do not want the page to reload again after submitting the file so i want to use ajax and jquery for this. Call the view through the url and execute the code. This is the url:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), ------->this is the page with the form, i do not want this page to reload

url(r'^work/$', views.d_s_w, name='d_s_w'),--->page that points to the view that takes the file and does some work with that file.
```

To do this i am using this code:

```
<script>
    $("#formi").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'd_s_w' %}",
             data: {
                    file: $('form').serialize(),
                    },
             success: function(data){
                    console.log("success")
                },

             error : function(xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
                }
        });
   });
```

So, running this i see that the view is called correctly with a POST method, BUT there is no file getting to the view, the request is empty:

[image]

Obviously i am doing something or many things wrong but i can not see where.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: processData: false,
contentType: false in ajax maybe?

Comment: @PauloPessoa no luck, thanks for the tip though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822823/django-jquery-ajax-file-upload look this, maybe help you

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is how i managed to send the file to my view:

```
$("#formi").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'd_s_w' %}",
             data: data,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',

             success: function(data){
                    console.log("success")
                },

             error : function(xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
                }
        });
   });
```

Now is getting there and the code is running.

I am not being able to see the data that is being returned from the view, but i will work on it. Thanks for e comments