# How to get image from input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to send image from an html page to Django view. But I am not able to attain the data. The following is my code.

```
<input type="file" id = "imageupload" onchange = "sendimg()" />

<script>
  var sendimg = function(){
    var img = document.getElementById("imageupload")
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/test/",
      data: {
        "imgfile": img,
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data){
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
      },
      failure: function(data){
        console.log("failure");
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
  }
</script>
```

The Django view is

```
@csrf_exempt
def testimg(request):
  print "the request",request.POST
  data = {"data": "ok"}
  return JsonResponse(data)
```

The print statement gives

```
the request <QueryDict: {}>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look on [documenataion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/)

and for [Ajax see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822823/django-jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .val() to get contents of an input field?
http://api.jquery.com/val/